# JSON JQuery array value in MVC 4 Controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing JSON JQuery value from view to controller in MVC4. When I am adding alert on view page, I am getting below array value -

```
[["28231","5"],["28402","5"]]
```

When I am getting value in controller it looks below -

```
"[[\"28231\",\"5\"],[\"28402\",\"5\"]]"
```

My JQuery code is -

```
     $(document).on('click', '.sOrder', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var rows = $('tbody tr', $('#tbl')).map(function () {
            return [$('td input', this).map(function () {
                return $(this).val();                
            }).get()];
        }).get();
        console.log(rows);


        var url = '@Url.Action("GetDetails")';
        var data = { rows: JSON.stringify(rows) };
        $.post(url, data, function (result) {

        });
    });
```

I need to insert these values in database table. But I am not sure how can I achieve these by using the above values.

Please someone help me to solve this issue. I am happy to follow any option.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're passing the array as a string. Have you set a `contentType` parameter in your AJAX request?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? JSON_Query function would remove the escapes if you're wanting to save it like a nested array. Though you might want to look at JSON_Value if you're sql server supports it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes i did, also use JSON.stringify(rows) when posting

Comment: @Jarealist, I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Jackbd that doesn't mean you're sending JSON. It's just JSON encoded. You could still be sending it as x-form-urlencoded, which is the default. It would help a lot here if you showed the actual AJAX request code in the question as well as the controller code which is receiving the request

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag as it has nothing to do with the problem of sending/receiving data in between JS and your MVC controller

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have edited my question and added my jquery code

Comment: What format you want it to be stored in database? Kindly add database schema

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal, I am happy with any format

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal, DB is - ID, PCode, Qty. value will be added to PCode and Qty column

Comment: csharp or vb? Doesn't csharp auto escape strings? (asking for a friend XD)

Comment: @Jarealist, its c#, it's not auto escaping

Comment: You trying to post an array of arrays. What is the signature if the POST method and how do you want to save this data? (the only way your data could bind is to a `string rows` parameter since your using `JSON.stringify` to make it a `string` which makes no sense - you cannot mix the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` contentTypes like that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, could you please give me an example, I can follow any options, when I am posting without Json.stringify, I am receiving null value in controller

Comment: You need to show you controller method and what is is that your wanting to save and how.

Comment: I didn't done anything in controller except getting the posting value from view, I don't know what I need to do after that

Comment: But what do you want to do with that data? (the format your posting does not really make sense)

Comment: I like save those data in a SQL table, first value for code and second value for quantity. In the example, I have 2 codes and 2 quantity numbers. It might be more,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156055/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-arif-chowdhury).